# Getting an error while building a CI action using Fastlane on Github (iOS App)

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, github-actions, fastlane

I am using Github actions to apply CI to my iOS project which uses Cocapods

```
name: Pull Request

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - test/ci
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cancel Previous Runs
        uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.1
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}

      - uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-xcode@v1
        with:
          xcode-version: latest-stable

      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '2.6'
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Install gems
        run: bundle install

      - name: Swift Packages Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: cache
        with:
          path: |
            Build/SourcePackages
            Build/Build/Products
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-deps-v1-${{ hashFiles('BILDsolid.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-deps-v1-
      - name: Run Tests (No Cache)
        if: steps.setup.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: bundle exec fastlane unit_test
      - name: Run Tests (Cache)
        if: steps.setup.outputs.cache-hit == 'true'
        run: bundle exec fastlane unit_test skip_package_dependencies_resolution:true
```

**The job that fails is this job:-**

```
- name: Run Tests (No Cache)
        if: steps.setup.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: bundle exec fastlane unit_test
```

*Error Message:-*

> error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'MyProject' from project 'MyProject')

Here's my Fastlane's files content

`Scanfile`

```
workspace "MyProject.xcworkspace"
scheme "MyProject"
sdk "iphonesimulator"
device "iPhone 14"
code_coverage true
xcargs '-parallelizeTargets'
prelaunch_simulator true
derived_data_path "Build/"
```

`Fastfile`

```
fastlane_version '2.157'
default_platform :ios

platform :ios do
    desc 'Builds project and executes unit tests'
    lane :unit_test do |options|
      # scan(
      #   clean: options[:clean],
      #   skip_package_dependencies_resolution: options[:skip_package_dependencies_resolution]
      # )
      run_tests(
        workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "MyProjectTests",
        slack_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/...",
        slack_channel: "#ios-tests"
      )
    end
end
```

I expect that CI run the test cases not failing before so